# resolving dependency error in intellij ide?

Tags: spring-security, grails-2.2

I created a new grails 2.2 app and added

```
compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
```

in plugins inside BuildConfig.groovy. Please note that i am using grails 2.2.

I then ran > grails compile and it throws the following error.

```
|Loading Grails 2.2.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
........
|Compiling 156 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\grails\plugins\springsecurity\BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:20: error: package org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding does not exist
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;
                                                           ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\grails\plugins\springsecurity\BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
public class BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {
                                              ^
  symbol: class PasswordEncoder
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\grails\plugins\springsecurity\DigestAuthPasswordEncoder.java:21: error: package org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding does not exist
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;
                                                           ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\grails\plugins\springsecurity\DigestAuthPasswordEncoder.java:22: error: package org.springframework.security.core.codec does not exist
import org.springframework.security.core.codec.Hex;
                                              ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\grails\plugins\springsecurity\DigestAuthPasswordEncoder.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
public class DigestAuthPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder, InitializingBean {
                                                  ^
  symbol: class PasswordEncoder
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:31: error: package org.springframework.security.access does not exist
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionVoter;
                                          ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:32: error: package org.springframework.security.access does not exist
import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
                                          ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:33: error: package org.springframework.security.access does not exist
import org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig;
                                          ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:34: error: package org.springframework.security.access.vote does not exist
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter;
                                               ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:35: error: package org.springframework.security.access.vote does not exist
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter;
                                               ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:36: error: package org.springframework.security.web does not exist
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation;
                                       ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:37: error: package org.springframework.security.web.access.expression does not exist
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionHandler;
                                                         ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:38: error: package org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept does not exist
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource;
                                                        ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:39: error: package org.springframework.security.web.util does not exist
import org.springframework.security.web.util.AntUrlPathMatcher;
                                            ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:40: error: package org.springframework.security.web.util does not exist
import org.springframework.security.web.util.UrlMatcher;
                                            ^
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
       implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource, InitializingBean {
                  ^
  symbol: class FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
    private UrlMatcher _urlMatcher;
            ^
  symbol:   class UrlMatcher
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
    private RoleVoter _roleVoter;
            ^
  symbol:   class RoleVoter
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    private AuthenticatedVoter _authenticatedVoter;
            ^
  symbol:   class AuthenticatedVoter
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
    private WebSecurityExpressionHandler _expressionHandler;
            ^
  symbol:   class WebSecurityExpressionHandler
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    private final Map<Object, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> _compiled = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>();
                                         ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
    protected static final Collection<ConfigAttribute> DENY = Collections.emptyList();
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                      ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
    protected abstract String determineUrl(FilterInvocation filterInvocation);
                                           ^
  symbol:   class FilterInvocation
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
    private Collection<ConfigAttribute> findConfigAttributes(final String url) throws Exception {
                       ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:158: error: cannot find symbol
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
                      ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:178: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setUrlMatcher(final UrlMatcher urlMatcher) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class UrlMatcher
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:209: error: cannot find symbol
    protected UrlMatcher getUrlMatcher() {
              ^
  symbol:   class UrlMatcher
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
    public Map<Object, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> getConfigAttributeMap() {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:254: error: cannot find symbol
    protected Collection<ConfigAttribute> buildConfigAttributes(final Collection<String> tokens) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:269: error: cannot find symbol
    protected boolean supports(final ConfigAttribute config) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:274: error: cannot find symbol
    private boolean supports(final ConfigAttribute config, final AccessDecisionVoter voter) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class ConfigAttribute
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:274: error: cannot find symbol
    private boolean supports(final ConfigAttribute config, final AccessDecisionVoter voter) {
                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class AccessDecisionVoter
  location: class AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition
C:\Users\sanjayg\.grails\2.2.0\projects\ACLTest\plugins\spring-security-core-
```

I appreciate any guide to why i am getting this error when compiling dependencies. Is it because it couldnt find the old plugin from the repository. I have also added the following repositories.

```
 mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"

 mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/"
```

Thanks!

Comment: try grails clean && grails compile

Comment: sorry that didnt work. I notice that org.springframework.security is currently missing. i am wondering whether i need to add springframework jar to the project.

Comment: You can verify their existence in /lib

Comment: ok the problem is clearly that import org.springframework.security doesnt exist in the newly created app. org.springframework.security is required in order for the spring security plugin to work. I wonder why security package is missing. Is there a way to go back to the old spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

Add spring security plugin in **BuildConfig.groovy** as follws,

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
     dependencies {
       //OTHER PLUGINS here
       runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.7.RELEASE"
     }
     plugins {
      //OTHER PLUGINS here
     compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC5'
     }
}
```

Do grails clean and grails compile or run-app

Comment: i am stuck with 1.2.7.3 for the moment